# How to iterate over two arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simultaneously Iterating Over Two Sets of Elements in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617735/simultaneously-iterating-over-two-sets-of-elements-in-jquery)

I have two variables:

```
var $distance = $(".distance");

var $classification = $(".classification");
```

For each non-empty item of the `$distance` collection I want to check if the corresponding `$classification` item is not empty. How do I do this?

Comment: You may want to check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/617735/simultaneously-iterating-over-two-sets-of-elements-in-jquery In one of the answers there is a snippet of code that uses the zip plugin. That is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question omits almost all key details, but it does sound like you want to do [a 'zip' operation, like in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617735/simultaneously-iterating-over-two-sets-of-elements-in-jquery/617747#617747).

In this case, depending on how your HTML was laid out, something like this should work:

```
var bError  = false

if ($distance.length != $classification.length) {
    //--- Error!, length mismatch.
}
else {
    $distance.each ( function (J, node) {
        var distVal     = $( node ).val (). trim ();
        var classVal    = $( $classification[J] ).val (). trim ();

        if {!distVal  ||  !classVal} {
            bError  = true;
            return false;
        }
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you meaning this?

```
if ($distance.length && $classification.length) {
     //do some stuff
}
```

Comment: yes,here i have to check for the whether the $distance values and $classification values are empty

Comment: @Vinay: They will not be "*empty*". This will work fine. This checks your selector(s) match the same number of elements as each other.